# TestNG classes run in parallel, but methods don't. How do I configure my testng.xml file and test classes so methods will also run in parrallel?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a suite of Selenium WebDriver tests that I'm running with Grid.  When I run this testng.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="20">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="testcases.test1"/>
      <class name="testcases.test2"/>
      <class name="testcases.test3"/>
      <class name="testcases.test4"/>
      <class name="testcases.test5"/>
      <class name="testcases.test6"/>
      <class name="testcases.test7"/>
      <class name="testcases.test8"/>
      <class name="testcases.test9"/>
      <class name="testcases.test10"/>
      <class name="testcases.test11"/>
      <class name="testcases.test12"/>
      <class name="testcases.test13"/>
      <class name="testcases.test14"/>
      <class name="testcases.test15"/>
      <class name="testcases.test16"/>
      <class name="testcases.test17"/>
      <class name="testcases.test18"/>
      <class name="testcases.test19"/>
      <class name="testcases.test20"/>
      <class name="testcases.test21"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Multiple browsers open, each running the @BeforeClass method and the first @Test method.  However, after each browser finishes that first @Test method, it will wait for all the other browsers to finish their respective first @Test method.

The tests are structured like this:

```
public class sampleTestClass {
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup(){
        //setup Remote WebDriver
    }
    @Test
    public void method1(){
        //do things
    }
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "method1")
    public void method2(){
        //do things
    }
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "method2")
    public void method3(){
        //do things
    }
    @AfterClass
    public void teardown(){
        //call teardown
    }

}
```

with multiple @Test methods in each class.  I will add that everything runs the way I prefer when I use this .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="MySuite" parallel="tests" thread-count="20">
  <test name="First Test">
    <classes>
       <class name="testcases.test1"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Second Test">
    <classes>
       <class name="testcases.test2"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Third Test">
    <classes>
       <class name="testcases.test3"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Fourth Test">
    <classes>
       <class name="testcases.test4"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <!--<test name="Fifth Test">
    <classes>
       <class name="testcases.test5"/>
    </classes>
  </test>-->
  <test name="Sixth Test">
    <classes>
       <class name="testcases.test6"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Seventh Test">
    <classes>
       <class name="testcases.test7"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

The reason I'm not okay with this configuration is that one, I don't think it preserves the semantic meaning of the tags at all, and two (and most importantly) I'd like to be able to run the automatically generated suite of failures in parallel, but the configuration of that .xml file is the same as the top one that I'm having trouble with.

It seems to me that specifying parallel="classes" in the suite tag is consistent with the TestNG documentation, but doesn't achieve asynchronous execution of the @Test methods in the separate classes.

Why doesn't this configuration of the .xml file work?  What do I need to do differently to make it work?

Comment: can you remove dependsOnMethod and try. From what i am observing is that it waits for all the first @Test method to finish because of dependsOnMethod attribute. Optionally you can use priority attribute.

Comment: @Mrunal Gosar in some cases I could try that, but in many places subsequent tests do actually depend on a prior test passing. I will look into priority.

Comment: You can do one thing. instead of adding dependsOnMethod. can you put all your tests in individual groups and make it group dependency. that worked for me.. coz even i was facing same issue. this might actually sound weird, but would worth to try it as it resolved same issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of a webdriver test class having multiple methods, given that there is one instance of a webdriver in that class, i dont see how it would be possible to share one webdriver instance simultanously between methods.  I seems it would HAVE TO call methods one at a time so that each method had its turn with the webdriver instance.   Otherwise it seems you would get some sort of concurrent exception.

I've tried many times to get parallel methods working with TestNG but never succeeded.   [There is an example in the source code though](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/b64b7e399ee30518b0fa25262c02cdd91db5a6ca/src/test/java/test/thread/TestThreadCountTest.java) that might be a clue; just look at the testng.xml in the same folder.

Comment: Yes, but while methods must be called one at a time within the same class in its own thread, they should be able to execute independently of the methods of a different class in a different thread, right?

Comment: Yes, but then your still just talking about just parallel classes.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I should have worded that differently. I'm really trying to figure out why the classes don't execute independently of other classes in different threads. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I've never had a problem running multiple threaded classes using TestNG.  I personally think your problem is that you wired the classes using BeforeClass annotation when you should have used BeforeTest annotation.  See the TestNG docs.

Comment: I'll give that a go in a second. Thanks.

Comment: I changed all the BeforeClass annotations to BeforeTest annotation.  Now 5 browsers load up and load the first URL like they should and then just hang, doing nothing else.

Comment: Looking at your original question, i would expect you would see 7 browsers load up and hang.  Are you sure you saw only 5?   One thing you could do is have only one Test method per class and then you could parameterize input to the methods and also generate a new webdriver instance in the dataprovider and send it along as a argument to the method making the Before method unnecessary.   Just a thought.  Otherwise,  I think it would help to solve your issue if you would share your POC on GitHub for us?

Comment: I am. I was keeping careful track.